# Why am I getting 403 Forbidden Request Error?

Tags: android, https, dart, get, flutter

I'm trying to download a pdf file using Dart programming language and Flutter framework.

If I send a GET request with my Browser or Postman everything works fine. However when I try using:

```
await http.readBytes("https://www.nato.int/structur/recruit/documents/Close%20Protection%20Agent,%20Close%20Protection%20Unit.pdf")
```

> I get Request to ... failed with status 403: Forbidden.

I'm using this import

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Why requesting from browser works and dynamically I get this error. If my url is bad encoded how should I encode it ? Isn't it already properly encoded ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The server is responding with 403, you need to check there

Comment: ok, but how come the browser is able to handle the get request, while flutter doesn't work ? I also do not have access to the server.

Comment: Only on the phone a few days. I'd need to investigate on a computer. Might be a check for the user agent header that's different between browser and programmatic request from Dart oe something along these lines.

Comment: Probably.. I have never worked with that header, but thanks for pointing me into a useful direction anyway. I have to mention it also works in Postman app.

Comment: Can only imagine some header difference.

Comment: I have same issue, in my postman its working fine but in flutter code same request gives 403

Comment: do you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by using [http.readBytes()](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/readBytes.html). What you can do here is wait for a response from `http.post()` and write the response to the device's storage.

```dart
final response = await http.post(uri);

Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
File file = File('$tempPath/yourFile.pdf');
await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
```